# KeyError: 'Resize' Error in converting from ONNX model to keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, yolo, stacking

I am trying to convert an ONNX model to a Keras model using onnx2keras, so that I can implement this: (https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/) stacking model on Yolov5. It will convert the majority of the model, but seems to say that Resize is not an available converter.

I was just wondering whether anyone had ran into this issue/knows a fix?

[image: this is the error]

Comment: I don't think onnx2keras support the 'Resize' operation, which is used in your ONNX model. Why don't you go for ONNX-TensorFlow converter.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much for your response, that's what i was worried about. The issue I am currently facing is that I haven't found a stacking implementation that uses only tensorflow